# Pass SpannableString to function, return SpannableString

Tags: java, spannablestring

I'm using a snippet of code that seeks through a SpannableString text for a regular expression and removes the first and last characters of any instances of that expression - in this case, text bound by [square brackets].

The output should be the same SpannableString, but without the brackets. eg:

```
input: Text [that] looks [like this]
output: Text that looks like this
```

However, I can't get the syntax right to call the function and return the text in the SpannableString format.

Here's the code snippet which does the conversion:

```
public static CharSequence removeSquareBracketsFromText(CharSequence text) {

    SpannableStringBuilder outputText = new SpannableStringBuilder( text );

    if( pattern != null )
    {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( text );
        int matchesSoFar = 0;
        while( matcher.find() )
        {
            int start = matcher.start() - (matchesSoFar * 2);
            int end = matcher.end() - (matchesSoFar * 2);
            outputText.setSpan( text, start + 1, end - 1, 0 );
            outputText.delete(start, start + 1);
            outputText.delete(end - 2, end -1);
            matchesSoFar++;
        }
    }
    return outputText;
}
```

And when I'm passing the SpannableString into the function, I (attempt to) do it like this:

```
SpannableString outputText= removeSquareBracketsFromText(inputText);
```

I suspect the error is in the syntax of the way I'm calling the function, but I don't know for sure. My IDE (Eclipse) tells me the error is in the word (removeSquareBracketsFromText': "Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to SpannableString".

Any help appreciated. As you can probably tell I'm fairly new to Java and am used to MATLAB which handles variable type conversion in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change method declaration to this:

```
public static SpannableString removeSquareBracketsFromText(CharSequence text) {
```

And change return statment to this:

```
    return new SpannableString(outputText);
```

Comment: Oh no! That's removed the [square brackets] but has also lost all the formatting I had on the text. Could that have been caused by the '.toString()'? To clarify, the SpannableString I feed in (and should get out) contains URL links.

Comment: Yes! It was. Seems that the return statement should not include the '.toString()'. Then it works perfectly (I've edited your answer to reflect this)

Comment: In that case you prolly want to keep it as a SpannableStringBuilder.
You can do this: textView.setText(ssb);